# How to stop or disable ngbTypeahead input field from opening on focus until it finishes mapping all the data

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I need the typeahead to show the first 5 results when clicked on the input field. I have already made a solution using the ngbTypeahead [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#focus).

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="form-group g-0 mb-3">
  <input id="typeahead-prevent-manual-entry" type="text" class="form-control"
  placeholder="Big dataset"
  formControlName="bigDataset"
  [ngbTypeahead]="search"
  [inputFormatter]="valueFormatter"
  [resultFormatter]="valueFormatter"
  [editable]="false"
  [focusFirst]="false"
  (focus)="stateFocus$.next($any($event).target.value)"
  (click)="stateClick$.next($any($event).target.value)"
  #instance="ngbTypeahead" />
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
type BigDataset: {
  id: string,
  name: string
}

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  dataset: BigDataset[];

  @ViewChild('instance', {static: true}) instance: NgbTypeahead;
  focus$ = new Subject<string>();
  click$ = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      bigDataset: ["", [Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  getBigDataset() {
    //Excluded for simplicity. This returns a set of objects (~3000)
    //of type BigDataset and assigns it to this.dataset.
  }

  valueFormatter = (value: any) => value.name;

  search: OperatorFunction<string, readonly BigDataset[]> = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(debounceTime(100), distinctUntilChanged());
    const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$.pipe(filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()));
    const inputFocus$ = this.focus$;

    return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(map(term => (term === '' ? this.dataset
        : this.dataset.filter(data => data.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 5))
    );
  };
}
```

Now this **works**. However, the problem is if I click on the input field immediately after the page initialisation, I get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')
    at org-address.component.ts:93:109
    at map.js:7:1
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:9:1)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:1)
    at subscribe._OperatorSubscriber__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.OperatorSubscriber.innerComplete (mergeInternals.js:25:1)
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:9:1)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:1)
    at Subject.js:31:1
    at errorContext (errorContext.js:19:1)
    at Subject.next (Subject.js:26:21)
```

From what I can understand this is because the typeahead tries to show data before it finishes the map function. The problem is the time it takes to map can increase if I decided to increase the dataset, so waiting an unknown amount of time until it finishes the process is not an option. I would like to disable the field or use another solution until it finished the mapping process.

I have tried disabling the form field and enabling it after the mapping process using finalize(), but I seem to have made a mistake and the field stays disabled.

```
search: OperatorFunction<string, readonly BigDataset[]> = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    this.dataForm.get('bigDataset')?.disable();
    const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(debounceTime(100), distinctUntilChanged());
    const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$.pipe(filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()));
    const inputFocus$ = this.focus$;

    return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
      finalize(() => this.dataForm.get('bigDataset')?.enable()),
      map(term => (term === '' ? this.dataset
        : this.dataset.filter(data => data.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 5))
    );
  };
```

Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can just initialize dataset which will stop the crashing and when the user starts typing he will endup with some data eventually. Otherwise use an observable inside the get big data and make it emit something when its filled. Doing so you would be able to enable the field.

Comment: Hey, thank you. I couldn't try your method yet, but I managed to fix this by adding optional chaining before calling the splice method. It stopped giving an error and even started returning the spliced data after filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine actually gave me a very simple fix for this, which was to add optional chaining after data filtering (before the splicing process). **Adding '?' before calling the slice method worked like a charm** and stopped giving an error if it tried returning the value before the filtering process is completed.

```
search: OperatorFunction<string, readonly BigDataset[]> = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(debounceTime(100), distinctUntilChanged());
    const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$.pipe(filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()));
    const inputFocus$ = this.focus$;

    return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(map(term => (term === '' ? this.dataset
        : this.dataset.filter(data => data.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1))?.slice(0, 5))
    );
  };
```